# NSURL without %

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing my drag&drop method. How can I get `NSUrl` without `%` where spaces should be? I convert NSUrl to NSString later, but I can't tell NSString to replace `%` with space, because there is some possibility that user will drag file with `%` symbol in name. So then that file wouldn't be located correctly. Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `path` method of your `NSUrl` instance, it unescapes the percent `%` sequences, replacing them with their corresponding "raw" characters.

You can convert between escaped and unescaped strings by using `NSString`'s `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` and `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` methods.

Comment: The first explanation is incorrect. The `path` will not contain any query strings in the URL. Use the `absoluteString` of the URL and the string-replace methods mentioned above.